# Выбор класса при создании объекта

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть абстрактный класс `К`, на основе которого (наследование) созданы три других класса `К1`, `К2`, `К3`. Создаваемый в программе объект `О` должен быть создан как объект одного из классов (`К1`, `К2`, `К3`) **в зависимости от выбора пользователя**.

Вопрос: **как это должно выглядеть?** Я пытался через `switch`, внутри которого объект `О` создается в зависимости от выбора пользователя, но *Visual Studio* такой вариант создания объектов считает "неопределенным" (выдает ошибки). Еще пытался создать объект `О` в классе `К1`, а в `switch`-е при необходимости его убивать и пересоздавать, но снова мимо...

Answer (score 2):

Жалко, что Вы не привели код, который выдает ошибки, потому что идея, в общем-то, правильная.

```
K* create(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 1: return new K1;
        case 2: return new K2;
        case 3: return new K3;
    }
}
```

Предположу, что Вы пытались использовать передачу по значению вместо указателя.

В предложенном варианте нужно не забывать освобождать выделенную память после того, как созданный объект перестает быть нужным. В современном c++ имеет смысл в подобных ситуациях использовать умные указатели, в частности `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Не получается (conversion to inaccessible base class is not allowed) - по видимому по той причине, что класс К абстрактный.

Comment: Заработало после того, как в описании классов К1, К2, К3 я добавил public.

Comment: "Заработало" в том смысле, что эта функция воспринимается студией без ошибок. Подскажите, а как же с помощью этой функции теперь создать нужный объект? Ведь перед именем создаваемого объекта нужно указать класс? А какой? К - нельзя (он же абстрактный)

Comment: Кажется, уже работает. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Дима если ответ помог Вам - проголосуйте (стрелки слева), если решил проблему - отметьте галочкой (там же).